# Apache Kafka for Time Series Data Persistence

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a system (say System A) that receives time series data via HTTP and this data is being persisted in OpenTSDB via the REST interface of the OpenTSDB. I would now like to introduce Apache Kafka into the system. The idea for me would be to have a Kafka server running, where System A as soon as receiving time series messages, publishes this message to the Apache Kafka server.

I can then have a consumer that reads from the topic and writes this data to the OpenTSDB. I have a couple of questions with this approach:

With respect to the architecting the Producer and Consumer:

1. Can I have a standalone client where I will write consumers that just consume from the Kafka topic and write the messages into OpenTSDB
2. The producers will be part of System A and will publish messages to the respective topic

With respect to Kafka topics, the time series data is some metrics that have a key and a value and example of which is as below:

```
 "metric.metricType.tagName"
```

I will be having hundreds or even perhaps thousands of these different tagNames. How do I structure this information and represent this as a topic in Apache Kafka. I'm not sure if there is a limit on the number of topics that I could create.

Should I have one topic per tagName? What is the deal with partitioning the topic?

With respect to Apache Kafka partitioning, I have the following questions:

1. If I have a topic "Topic A" and have set partitions to 4 for this topic, and if my producer writes to this partition, in which partition of this topic will this message be available? Is the same message available across each partition within the same topic?
2. If I write a consumer for this partitioned topic, how will this behave, I mean, will this consumer receive the message from the partition?
3. If I have multiple consumers for this partitioned topic, will all of those consumers get the same messages? I mean if there are 4 partitions in the topic (TP1, TP2, TP3, TP4) and I have 4 consumer group (CG1, CG2, CG3, CG4) where in each consumer group, I have one consumer that reads the messages from the respective topic partition (C1 reads from TP1, C2 reads from TP2 and so on). Will I end up having duplicate messages if all my consumer groups writes the messages it receives to the same database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I have a standalone client where I will write consumers that just
>   consume from the Kafka topic and write the messages into OpenTSDB?

Yes, that's how I did it. A standalone java app (you might call it a "java server app").

> Should I have one topic per tagName?

If you'll want to treat messages with one tag differently that other tags, e.g. retention, message size (and [other topic-level settings](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#topic-config)) then it makes sense to have a separate topic, but if you're gonna have thousands of tags I'd rather not do that. It can be just a simple field inside a message. You can have one topic that will be used for your metrics and then, when you'll want to add other types of messages (and you'll surely want to do that once you see the benefit:) you can create a different topic for that. You can roughly look at topics as entities in a database, but that's a rather weak comparison, since it depends on many factors, like size, incoming rate and similar stuff. There's no one-size-fits-all recipe, so you'll have to ask a separate, specific question, with all the parameters you have.

> What is the deal with partitioning the topic?

Partitions are the consumption parallelism mechanism of Kafka (they also facilitate redundancy, since each partition is replicated across brokers, depending on replication factor you choose). Since partition cannot be consumed by more than one consumer thread, you'll want to create more partitions initially (and start consuming with a smaller number of threads), so that you can later increase number of threads up to number of partitions. (This restriction might have been lifted in the latest Kafka version, 0.9. This rule applies to low-level consumer of v0.8).

> If I have a topic "Topic A" and have set partitions to 4 for this
>   topic, and if my producer writes to this partition, in which partition
>   of this topic will this message be available?

If you publish messages like you described, you won't know in which partition a message will end up.
This is determined by hashing at the producer side and default hashing mechanism is random (something like "round robin").
You can control partitioning by determining the attribute(s) that will be used for hashing. E.g. if you include your `tag` in hash, all messages with a same tag will always go to the same partition. This is important when you want to assure that messages with the same tag get consumed in the same order they were put into Kafka i.e. produced.

> Is the same message available across each partition within the same topic?

No, partitions always contain a roughly equal subset of messages of their topic (if default, random hashing is used).

> If I write a consumer for this partitioned topic, how will this
>   behave, I mean, will this consumer receive the message from the
>   partition?

Messages will be consumed randomly, since there's no coordination between consumer threads. Understandably, of course, since that would incur a huge performance penalty.

> If I have multiple consumers for this partitioned topic, will all of
>   those consumers get the same messages?

This depends on the consumer group. All consumer threads that are in a same group receive in total 100% of messages (e.g. each of the 4 consumer threads would get 25% of messages from that topic). If, on the other hand, you have 2 consumers with different groups, they would each consume 100% of messages from that topic. I think you can deduce answers to your last two question from this, right?

Comment: 1. I guess you meant a standalone client app?

Comment: Client in the "Kafka consumer client" sense, but generally looking it's like a small server, since it's a long running task that does something. Mine also has REST interface that can be used to get some consumption metrics, pull out a single message at a particular offset and control some configuration params (that can be dynamically changed).

Comment: I did not quite understand your statement "No, partitions always contain a roughly equal subset of their topic...." Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Topic consists of (is split on) partitions, so let's say you have 2 partitions. Random-hashing producer will send roughly 50% of all messages to `partition0` and the other 50% to `partition1`. More generally, if you have N partitions, each of those will contain 1/N of total number of messages in that topic (when round robin, i.e. random hashing is used).

Comment: How is this partitioning supposed to work with time series data? Assume if T1, T2... Tn are time series data and I have a topic with 2 partitions. Now as the T's come in, assume that T1 goes to topic partition P1, T2 goes to P2 and so on. When I read these T's using my consumer, which is then going to persist the data in Cassandra, I could end up persisting T3 before T2. I definitely do not wan to end up in this situation. Could you please comment on this?

Comment: Why is out-of-order problem, given that you're dealing with metrics? You'll have a timestamp as one of the fields, right? Cassandra, not HBase (aha, I see, you're using AsyncCassandra)?

Comment: The consumers C1 and C2 within the same consumer group might be reading from P1 and P2 and might be out of sync or?

Comment: If "out of sync" means "out of order" then yes. You cannot guarantee ordering across partitions.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of partitioning the topic if I have the same set of messages across all the partitions?

Comment: Who said you have the same set across partitions? I've just written the comment describing partitions, the one that starts with "Topic consists of...". BTW can you accept the answer/upvote?